# R ggplot_2 facet_plots strip text with sub and superscript and line break

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

I am new here but I read in this forum for a longer time and gained a lot of knowledge in R.
However, currently I am struggling in changing the text strip in facet plots in ggplot2.
I tried to use the text strips to Label the y-axis by flipping them to the right side. This actually works fine, also a line break was no problem. 
What I am not able to create are Special characters. I tried both variants described here:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/ 
under Header:
"Modifying facet label text"

Other methods of labelling as described here http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/labellers.html 
I can unfortunatly not transfer to my code.

Here a part of my code as example: (In both cases, '-1' should be superscript)

```
###Try to use labels
labels<-c(Cmic="Cmic \n [g kg-1]", Corg="Corg \n [g kg-1]")

###Instead: Try to Change levels
levels(Bodenbiologie$Größe)[levels(Bodenbiologie$Größe)=="Cmic"]<-"Cmic~\n~ [g kg-1]"
levels(Bodenbiologie$Größe)[levels(Bodenbiologie$Größe)=="Corg"]<-"Corg~\n~[g kg-1]"
```

It would be really nice, if somebody could help my!

Thanks in advance!

Here now a reproducible dummy example of the Problem:

```
Variante <- c("D","D","D","C","C","C")
Bezeichnung <- c("Treat","Treat","Treat","Con","con","con")
Größe <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C")
mean <- c(5,10,15,7,14,21)
standdev <- c(2.5,5,7.5,3.5,7,10.5)

Problem<-data.frame(Variante, Bezeichnung, Größe, mean, standdev)


library(ggplot2)
attach(Problem)
names(Problem)

labels<-c(A="Test \n (Test^1)", B="SOM \n (g kg^{-1} d.m.)", C=" Check \n (kg[2])")


Abb1<-ggplot(Problem, aes(x=Bezeichnung, y=mean, fill=(Größe)))+
geom_boxplot(stat="boxplot", position = "dodge", width=0.5)+
labs(title="", x= "", y="")
Abb1


Abb2<-Abb1 + facet_grid(Größe~., scale="free_y", switch="both",labeller=labeller(Größe=labels))+
stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width=0.5) + 
geom_boxplot(stat="boxplot", position = "dodge", width=0.75)

Abb2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by including the code for your plot with a minimal example dataset.  That will help people help you. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) contains good info for making your question reproducible.

Comment: Hello together, has nobody an idea how to solve the issue?